# Using dynamic url in angular html gives error.

Tags: angular

In my HTML i am using like:

```
<object #homes style="height:500px;width:1000px" data="{{homesPath}}"></object>
```

In TS:

```
constructor(
private homesProfileService: HomesProfileService,
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

this.homesPath = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
  environment.homesPath
);
```

But it is giving Error:

> Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Is there anything wrong that i am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working now by changing a bit in HTML from:

```
<object #homes style="height:500px;width:1000px" data="{{homesPath}}"></object>
```

TO:

```
<object #homes style="height:500px;width:1000px" [data]="homesPath"></object>
```

But still did not get the reason why the prior one was not working.
Can anyone comment on it.